# dynamically created HTML file input element doesn't post data

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload, dhtml

I have a form which is dynamically created using document.createElement. The components are created in the same way.  The form is used to upload a file to a PHP script and when submitted loads the reponse in an iframe specified by the target attribute of the form.

Unfortunately, the server receives a blank $_FILES array, and when I inspect the POST request I see that the file data wasn't included in the request.  If I instead, on-the-fly, use the Google Chrome developer tools to edit the dynamically created form (in this process i just EDIT and then change absolutely none of the code), form submissions thereafter work perfectly, sending the relevant file data.

So this makes me realise that there is nothing wrong with the construction of my form in html, because it worked without changing anything.  Which leads me to believe that the browser doesn't like me to dynamically create file input elements?

For completeness' sake, here is the dynamically generated form:

```
<form method="POST" action="includes/uploadPic.php" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" target="fileResponse">
  <input type="file" name="pic">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And `print_r($_FILES)` gives an empty array on the server.

Can anyone explain this to me?  My alternative is to statically create a hidden form in the document, and just append it to the relevant div when I need it, but I really dislike that kind of thing.

Below is the code that generates the form:

```
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var fileUpload  = document.createElement("input");
    var uploadBut   = document.createElement("input");

    form.setAttribute("method",  "POST");
    form.setAttribute("action",  "includes/uploadPic.php");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("target",  "fileResponse");
    fileUpload.setAttribute("type",  "file");
    fileUpload.setAttribute("name",  "pic");
    uploadBut.setAttribute ("type",  "submit");
    uploadBut.setAttribute ("value", "Upload");
    form.appendChild(fileUpload);
    form.appendChild(uploadBut);
    dlgContent.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: You aren't adding your dynamically created form inside of another <form> element are you?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual HTTP transaction to see what's being sent from the browser? There's at least one plugin for Firefox ([Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)) that will show you every HTTP transaction from the browser and let you check basically everything.

Comment: @AndrewR not a nested form
@Pointy I did mention that I inspected the POST Request.  Everything seemed correct except that it was as if the file input was being ignored..

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the form?

Comment: I've added the form-generating script

Comment: Are you doing this before or after the DOM is ready?

Comment: This is a user-event that occurs long after the DOM is ready.

Comment: FYI, seeing that it would work after I'd edited (but actually changed nothing) the markup using Chrome's inspector, I thought maybe I could do the same via javascript.  
So after appending `dlg`, I then did `dlg.innerHTML=dlg.innerHTML` and now it works. Why? I have no clue.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var fileUpload  = document.createElement("input");
var uploadBut   = document.createElement("input");

form.method = "POST";
form.action = "includes/uploadPic.php";
form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
form.target = "fileResponse"; /* I think you are trying to submit this from in an iframe */
fileUpload.type = "file";
fileUpload.name = "pic";
uploadBut.type = "submit";
uploadBut.value = "Upload";
form.appendChild(fileUpload);
form.appendChild(uploadBut);
dlgContent.appendChild(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `form` tag within a `div` tag, it does not post dynamically created elements to the server. However if you take it outside of the `div` or `table` tag, it works.